# How to make a query limit 1 linq C# MongoDB (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, linq

I want to pass data from a collection to a viewbag from mongoDB. How can I do the query (limit 1) to assign the result to the viewbag variable?

For example I want to pass the following query in LINQ

```
db.getCollection('monitoreo').find({valor:'002'}).limit(1)
```

I leave the example of my controller which returns the entire list and I pass to the view

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   List<monitoreoModel> monitoreo = monitoreoCollection.AsQueryable<monitoreoModel>().ToList();
    return View(monitoreo);
}
```

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Linq, you can follow the following sample:

```
var result = monitoreoCollection
  .AsQueryable()
  .Where(x => x.Valor == "002")
  .Take(1) // This is not required, but asserts that MongoDB returns only one document
  .FirstOrDefault()
```

Above code returns only the first matching item or null if none exists.

If you want to use a simple find command instead of an aggregation pipeline, you can use the following commands. `Limit` is only supported in the `async` versions of the `Find` command, so you have to change the action to `async`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
   var result = await (await monitoreoCollection.FindAsync(
       x => x.Valor == "002", 
       new FindOptions<EventBase, EventBase>() { Limit = 1 }))
     .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    return View(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I will do the tests in my code

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me a lot in the project.
another question...
FirstOrDefault retrieves the first one it finds, how can I retrieve the last result?

Comment: You can try `LastOrDefault()`, but you if you limit the results to one, you could also use `OrderByDescending(...)` together with `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: It works perfectly, I had searched for information but nothing helped me. Thank you very much for your support, you are very kind!